# what does `@objc(ViewController) ` do?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, google-analytics

I have this swift code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
...
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
        if (controller is InlineMainViewController ){
            mainViewController = controller as! InlineMainViewController
        }
        window?.rootViewController = controller
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

when my viewController has this attribute:

```
@objc(ViewController)  // match the ObjC symbol name inside Storyboard
public class InlineMainViewController: UIViewController,
```

`(controller is InlineMainViewController )` returns `false`

and when it doesn't have this attribute:

```
public class InlineMainViewController: UIViewController,
```

`(controller is InlineMainViewController )` returns `true`

My `Main.sotryboard` is connected to `InlineMainViewController`

I took `@objc(ViewController)` from Google analytics github example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Swift Type Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html)

> You can use the `@objc` attribute if your Swift class doesn’t inherit
>   from an Objective-C class, or if you want to change the name of a
>   symbol in your interface as it’s exposed to Objective-C code.

This code:

```
@objc(ViewController)
```

Will cause the class following this attribute to have the name in the parentheses when it is imported into Objective-C code through the generated header, as discussed in [Importing Swift into Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

> **To import Swift code into Objective-C from the same target**
>
> - Import the Swift code from that target into any Objective-C .m file
>     within that target using this syntax and substituting the appropriate
>     name:
>
>   `#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"`

Comment: how come this make my `(controller is InlineMainViewController )` return `false` ?

Comment: @EladBenda How did you designate the initial view controller?